# I can't figure out how to print this in the way I need

Tags: python, printing

```
for i in range(6):
    x = 6-i
    print(" " * x, end = '')
    for i in range(6):
        y = 1+i
        print("*" * y)
```

Output:

```
      *
**
***
****
*****
******
     *
**
***
****
*****
******
    *
**
***
****
*****
******
   *
**
***
****
*****
******
  *
**
***
****
*****
******
 *
**
***
****
*****
******
```

What I need it to print:

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

---

---

Comment: Why do you have two loops in this code?  One should do it.

Comment: And no, I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: There are only 4 lines in the triangle you want to print. Why are you looping 6 times?

Comment: Look for patterns in the output that relate to the line number. E.g. the number of spaces at the beginning of each line is `3 - line_number`.

Comment: I'll give you another hint: you need to print these 2 elements somehow: spaces `" "`, and stars separated by spaces: `" *"`. You can do it in one line if you want.

Comment: Please try to format the code lines using the editing options next time. It is hard to read and understand a question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create the wanted output. You will just need one single for loop.

```
num_stars=7
for i in range(1,num_stars+1):
    y = i
    x = num_stars-y
    print(f'{" "*x}{"* "*y}')
```

Output

```
      * 
     * * 
    * * * 
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
* * * * * * *
```